# XPending Function Is Blocking

Tags: c++, x11, blocking

I have a program that has the following basic structure:

```
while( true )
{
    // get any X11 events
    while( XPending( display ) > 0 )
    {
       // get an event using XNextEvent and do stuff with it
    }

    // draw to the display
 }
```

The program is rendering an opengl scene.  The problem I am having is that when I click and start dragging on the window, the `XPending` call get blocks until i finish the drag sequence, thus halting any animations that were in progress.  I can solve this solution by having another thread send `Expose` events and thus waking up the `XPending` call, but ideally I would like to have an X function that checks for events but does not block at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to process received events without blocking to wait for more, use `XEventsQueued(display, QueuedAlready)` instead of `XPending(display)`.

Comment: Thanks.  Turns out my problem was actually that my "draw to the display" code was inside the `XPending` while loop instead of outside like I have shown above.  Moving it outside of the loop cause everything to work right, so it appears that `XPending` was not really blocking as I had thought.